# Проблемы с JSON полями в RETROFIT 2

Tags: java, android, json, retrofit2

Есть необходимость отправить такой POST запрос с таки JSON:

```
{
  "title": "ТЕСТТЕСТ",
  "article": {
    "subject": "ТЕСТТЕСТ",
    "message": "ТЕСТЕТСТ"
  }
}
```

Не понимаю как задать поля в "article",
ретрофит2 уже плотно используется в проекте, пересаживаться с него никуда желания нет.

Как я понимаю, делать надо что-то типо этого, но естественно, ничего не получается

```
Call <TicketSendResponse> sendTickets(@Header("Authorization") String auth, @Field("title") String ticketName, @Field("article/subject") String subject,@Field("article/message") String message);
```

Comment: А что вы пытаетесь делать с помощью этого кода?

Comment: Отправить ПОСТ запрос, это интерфейс, очевидную часть я убрал, меня интересует как можно задать поля в article, остальное мне понятно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно отправить ваш запрос как `Body`

Как пример, ваш метод будет выглядеть так:

```
@POST("send_ticket")
Call<TicketResponse> sendTicket(@Body TicketRequest ticketRequest);
```

Класс тела запроса:

```
public class TicketRequest {

   public TicketRequest(String title, String subject, String message) {
      this.title = title;
      this.article = new Article(subject, message);
   }

   @SerializedName("title")
   public String title;

   @SerializedName("article")
   public Article article;

   public class Article {

      public Article(String subject, String message) {
         this.subject = subject;
         this.message = message;
      }

      @SerializedName("subject")
      public String subject;

      @SerializedName("message")
      public String message;

   }

}
```

Comment: Если будете следовать этому примеру, то не забудьте подключить Gson потому как аннотация @SerializedName недоступна из коробки

Comment: Большое спасибо, это действительно решило мою проблему.